# Why wont delete document from Xpages Dynamic View work

Tags: xpages

I have created a new XPage with a DynamicViewPanel that lists the documents in a certain Notes View.  Then I have the dynamic view panel configured to show a check box for each row.  I then created a button below the dynamic view panel with the plan to select a document(s) with the check box and click on the button to delete them.  Below is my Xpages code for the button but why won't this work please?

```
<xp:button value="Delete" id="delete">

   <xp:this.onclick submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewPanel=getComponent  
      ("dynamicViewPanel1");
     var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
       for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
         var docId=docIDArray[i];
         var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
         doc.remove(true);
     }}]]></xp:this.onclick>
</xp:button>
```

EDIT: Appears to be working now after changing to this below

```
<xp:button value="Delete" id="delete">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
   <xp:this.action>
     <xp:actionGroup>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewPanel=getComponent
          ("dynamicViewPanel1");
         var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
         for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
           var docId=docIDArray[i];
           var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
           doc.remove(true);
        }}]]>
      </xp:actionGroup>
     </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:button>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the correct ACL access.  If you haven't built the login functions yet, you will be username "Anonymous".  Make sure "Anonymous" has delete access.

Comment: @SteveZavocki The application has a login facility when I first open it in the browser

Comment: @SteveZavocki also, in the ACL I am in the group "Notes developers" and we have delete documents ticked

Comment: Did you verify that your array contained the checked documents.  Add a print statement in your for loop to write the Unique ID to the log.

Comment: @SteveZavocki thanks steve will try that ASAP

Comment: You don't exactly say what isn't working.  The error message or stack trace would help.  At least I assume you're getting an error somewhere.

Comment: @DavidLeedy There are no errors presented in the browser and no errors in the logs.  What isn't working is that the document which has its check box checked in the dynamic view panel is not deleting

Comment: @SteveZavocki  Found the edited version appears to work but does it look okay?  Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeedy Found the edited version appears to work but does it look okay?  Thanks

Comment: If it works then that is all that matters.

Comment: Cheers all.  I will post up the amendment as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and have posted it up as the edited code in the question.  Changed the tags in the button element to include an event handler and also included it in an action group tag

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered - though truth be told I'm not sure I like the code in the answer.  No it doesn't "look right".  I pasted that in to my designer and it doesn't look right.  It should be something like this I'd think:

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button3">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewPanel=getComponent
              ("dynamicViewPanel1");
             var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
             for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
               var docId=docIDArray[i];
               var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
               doc.remove(true);
               }}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```